# Python csv export includes binary flags (how to remove?)

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing, scrape

I tried to export a test table to csv... and the below code works.. 
But, when I open the test1.csv file, some lines have "b flag (looks like binary flags)
even when I remove the encode('utf8') , still get the b flags. 
How can I remove these b flags and have a clean csv file?

here is the entire code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
my_url = 'http://www.igobychad.com/test_table.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.find("table", { "id" : "Emp_sum" })
table = page_soup.find("table", { "id" : "Emp_sum" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
   cells = row.findAll("td")
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
with open('test1.csv', 'w') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)
       writer.writerow(headers)
       writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

results look like this:

```
Category,June2016,Apr.2017,May2017,June2017,Change from:May2017-June2017,Estatus,CN pop,Clf,Prate,Em,Ep ratio,Unem,Un rate
b''
"b'253,397'","b'254,588'","b'254,767'","b'254,957'",b'190'
"b'158,889'","b'160,213'","b'159,784'","b'160,145'",b'361'
```

Comment: Change `val.text.encode('utf8')` to `val.text`

Comment: ok, that took care of the "b" flags.. but results are still not formatted correctly like the html table on the page. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Write each cell individually?

Comment: You have to divide between _**Values**_ and _**Formatting_**_,  [Edit] your Question and show how are they different.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to change your code a bit to hopefully fit your table format in the csv output. Since csvwriter can only writer a row of data, I had to hack around to match your table format in the csv. It's not complete, but you can fix it to fit your format.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
my_url = 'http://www.igobychad.com/test_table.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.find("table", { "id" : "Emp_sum" })
table = page_soup.find("table", { "id" : "Emp_sum" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
cells = row.findAll("td")
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td') if val])

with open('test1.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Your table headers are only the first 6 elements of "headers" so we write them
    writer.writerow(headers[:6])
    # Next will will have to compose the row to write to the csv
    index = 1
    for txt in headers[7:]:

        index += 1
        # Every element in headers after the 6'th are actually row start
        # So we add it to an empty list called "string" (bad name, you can change it)
        string = [txt]
        # We extend the list with the list of values corresponding to the list index taken from the rows list
        # To get float values we replace coma with dot from the rows string then cast to float
        string.extend([float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in rows[index]])
        writer.writerow(string)
```

Comment: thank you! tried to apply to another table.. gave me error float vs string. Do we have to use float in the code? : ValueError     Traceback
     21         index += 1
     22         string = [txt]
---> 23         string.extend([float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in rows[index]])
     24         writer.writerow(string)
     25
     21         index += 1
     22         string = [txt]
---> 23         string.extend([float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in rows[index]])
     24         writer.writerow(string)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: I used the cast to float and the subsequent replace to save them as numbers in the csv, but you're right, you dont need that mumbo-jumbo. Just save it as text and be done. Instead on [float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in rows[index]] try [x for x in rows[index]]